# Security Exception: Request failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, code-access-security, securityexception, trust

[This page](http://sextaigreja.com.br/Downloads) presents a security problem.

Not yet identified the cause of the error.
This page was listing all the files in a folder, it worked perfectly. Now she is listing these same files, but using ajax.

The code is simple:
I have a PartialView, which is a WebGrid that lists the files in this folder:

**PartialView "_files.cshtml"**

```
@model string[]
@{
    var folderName = Request["FolderName"];

    var columns = new List<WebGridColumn>
                            {
                                { ... }
                            };

    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        columns.Add( { ... } );
    }

    var grid = new WebGrid(
        source: Model,
        ajaxUpdateContainerId: folderName + "-grid",
        rowsPerPage: 10);
}
@grid.GetHtml(columns: columns,
    headerStyle: "grid-header"
)
```

The request is made by this javascript funciton:

**Index.cshtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        loadFiles("Documentos");
    });

    function loadFiles(folderName) {
        $.ajax(
                { type: "GET",
                    url: '/Downloads/Files?folderName=' + folderName,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#" + folderName + "-grid").html(data);
                    }
                })
    }
</script>

<div id="Documentos-grid"></div>
```

**In the Controller, I call PartialView:**

```
public string[] GetFiles(string folderName)
{
    var locations = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Downloads/");
    return Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(locations, folderName));
}

public ActionResult Files(string folderName)
{
    return PartialView("_files", GetFiles(folderName));
}
```

**The files are sent to the folder**:

> /App_Data/Downloads/

Following [this article](http://www.ironspeed.com/Designer/8.0.2/WebHelp/Part_VI/Security_Exception_AspNetHostingPermission_Error.htm), I put a web.config in the Downloads folder, but the error remains.

**Web.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <location allowOverride="true">
    <system.web>
      <securityPolicy>
        <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal" />
        <trustLevel name="High" policyFile="web_hightrust.config" />
        <trustLevel name="Medium" policyFile="web_mediumtrust.config" />
        <trustLevel name="Low" policyFile="web_lowtrust.config" />
        <trustLevel name="Minimal" policyFile="web_minimaltrust.config" />
      </securityPolicy>
      <trust level="Medium" originUrl="" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

**Controller**

**The error happens at line 3 of the method: GetBoletins**

```
private DataContext db = new DataContext();

public IList<Boletim> GetBoletins()
{
    return (from boletim in db.BoletinsSemanais
            where boletim.Year == DateTime.Now.Year
            orderby boletim.Year, boletim.Week, boletim.Name
            select boletim).Take(5).ToList();
}
```

**Another Assembly**

**DataContext is a class that is in another assembly.**

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Boletim> BoletinsSemanais { get; set; }

    public DataContext()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, you don't have an [Authorize] attribute on the controller, do you?

Comment: No! This attribute is only in the create and delete actions